# How to hide input in python console

Tags: python, input, output, spyder

I'm using python on spyder and when I run my code the console shows the input as well as the output. I *know* what the input is, I don't need it taking up space where my results should be. How do I hide it?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to hide the input right now (2018/04). We're reconsidering to change this for our next major version (Spyder 4).